# Is There an algorithm to remove intersections between two tetrahedrons?

Tags: algorithm, mesh

I have a mesh made up of several tetrahedrons, I know for sure that there are intersections between some of them: how can I remove these intersections, without generating others?
In other terms: if between a couple of tetrahedrons there is an intersection, how can I remove it?

I found these articles: the [Method of Separating Axes](https://www.geometrictools.com/Documentation/MethodOfSeparatingAxes.pdf), the [Tetrahedron Overlap Algorithm](http://vcg.isti.cnr.it/Publications/2003/GPR03/fast_tetrahedron_tetrahedron_overlap_algorithm.pdf).
But they are only useful for checking if there are intersections or not.

Is there an algorithm to solve this problem?

Comment: To clarify for me, are you wanting methods to take a set of intersecting tets and produce a new set of tets that fill the same volume/shape but are non-intersecting.

Answer (score 1):

Since you already have convex shapes and started looking at the "Method of separating axis", then the [GJK](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gilbert%E2%80%93Johnson%E2%80%93Keerthi_distance_algorithm) algorithm is probably what you're looking for. This is commonly used in physics simulations to find collisions (for games, I don't know about computational science).

When you say "remove intersections without generating others", then you're asking for collision response. Multiple collision response is actually a tough beast. [Here](http://www.cs.columbia.edu/cg/rosi/rosi.pdf) (Reflections on Simultaneous Impact) is a paper that goes into more detail, but a very good introduction to this are course notes from Baraff:
[An Introduction to Physically Based Modeling: Rigid Body Simulation I—Unconstrained Rigid Body Dynamics](https://www.cs.cmu.edu/%7Ebaraff/sigcourse/notesd1.pdf) and part 2. [Rigid Body Simulation II-Nonpenetration Constraints](https://www.cs.cmu.edu/%7Ebaraff/sigcourse/notesd2.pdf)

Lastly, you can always use a physics engine for this, such as [Bullet3d](https://github.com/bulletphysics/bullet3).